# How can I convert relative paths to absolute paths with my scrapy CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to Scrapy and I am currently trying to write a CrawlSpider that will crawl a forum on the Tor darknet. Currently my CrawlSpider code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class HiddenAnswersSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ha'
    start_urls = ['http://answerstedhctbek.onion/questions']
    allowed_domains = ['http://answerstedhctbek.onion', 'answerstedhctbek.onion']
    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'answerstedhctbek.onion/\d\.\*', r'https://answerstedhctbek.onion/\d\.\*')), follow=True, process_links='makeAbsolutePath'),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, process_links='makeAbsolutePath')

            )

 def makeAbsolutePath(links):
    for i in range(links):
          links[i] = links[i].replace("../","")
    return links
```

Because the forum uses relative path, I have tried to create a custom process_links to remove the "../" however when I run my code I am still recieving:

```
2017-11-11 14:46:46 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../badges>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-11-11 14:46:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../general-guidelines> (referer: http://answerstedhctbek.onion/questions)
2017-11-11 14:46:47 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../general-guidelines>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-11-11 14:46:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../contact-us> (referer: http://answerstedhctbek.onion/questions)
2017-11-11 14:46:47 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../contact-us>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-11-11 14:46:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../questions?sort=hot> (referer: http://answerstedhctbek.onion/questions)
2017-11-11 14:46:48 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../questions?sort=hot>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-11-11 14:46:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET http://answerstedhctbek.onion/../questions?sort=votes> (referer: http://answerstedhctbek.onion/questions)
```

As you can see, I am still getting 400 errors due to the bad path. Why isn't my code removing the "../" from the links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that `makeAbsolutePaths` is not part of the spider class. [The documentation states](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule):

> `process_links` is a callable, or a string (in which case a method from the spider object with that name will be used)

You did not use `self` in `makeAbsolutePaths`, so I assume it is not an indentation error. `makeAbsolutePaths` also has some other errors. If we correct the code to this state:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class HiddenAnswersSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ha'
    start_urls = ['file:///home/user/testscrapy/test.html']
    allowed_domains = []
    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*')), follow=True, process_links='makeAbsolutePath'),
            )

    def makeAbsolutePath(self, links):
        print(links)
        for i in range(links):
            links[i] = links[i].replace("../","")
        return links
```

it will yield this error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is, because no call to `len()` was used in the call to `range` and `range` can only operate on integers. It wants a number and will give you the range from 0 to this number minus 1.

After fixing this issue, it will give the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Link' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

This is - because unlike you thought - `links` is not a list of strings containing the contents of `href=""` attributes. Instead, it is a list of `Link` objects.

I'd recommend you output the contents of `links` inside `makeAbsolutePath` and see, if you have to do anything at all. In my opinion, scrapy should already stop resolving `..` operators once it reaches the domain level, so your links should point to `http://answerstedhctbek.onion/<number>/<title>`, even though the site uses `..` operator without an actual folder level (as the URL is `/questions` and not `/questions/`).

Somehow like this:

```
    def makeAbsolutePath(self, links):
        for i in range(len(links)):
            print(links[i].url)

        return []
```

(Returning an empty list here gives you the advantage that the spider will stop and you can check the console output)

If you then find out, the URLs are actually wrong, you can perform some work on them through the `url` attribute:

```
links[i].url = 'http://example.com'
```

Comment: Aufziehvogel, it's finally working correctly thanks to you! I was unable to receive any of the errors you mentioned above until I added 'self' as a parameter in makeAbsolutePath. So adding 'self' including all the other resolutions you mentioned has resolved this. The urls were still wrong but I was able to simply include the line links[i].url = links[i].url.replace('../','')